# getElementByName even if that element are charged dynamically

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code:

```
<div name="testDyn" test_name="test1" test_value="234"></div>
<div name="testDyn" test_name="test2" test_value="bcd"></div>
<script>
  var testDyn = document.getElementsByName("testDyn");
  console.log(testDyn);
</script>
```

In the console log I can see the two elements with their attributes and everything. I'm just testing, but after that I'll send this info through ajax.

My question is, if dynamically another element with the name "testDyn" is loaded in the document, how could this script send that info to the console log ? (and later by ajax).

Thank in advance.

Comment: You would have to reset the variable in the success function of the AJAX call

Comment: do you mean the "testDyn" variable ?

Comment: Yes, the way you have it set up now, the variable is being set on page load, so only the elements that exist in the DOM on page load will be assigned to that variable. If you set the variable within the AJAX success function(at the end), it will include the elements that are being added to the DOM dynamically.

Comment: ok, I got it. But it looks like that is more complicated that send directly that data inside the AJAX call. Thanks any way!

Comment: It's not complicated at all, it's moving what you already have to a different spot in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

To reference tags specifically in the DOM, use id's.

`<div id="tag1" name="testDyn">` and then in javascript you can reference the tag by its id.  `document.getElementById("tag1").value`

Comment: I'm not sure that this reply has something to do with my question. I can't use ids because there is going to be multiples elements with the same identification, that's why I used name instead. Anyway, name or id, what I need is to capture elements which are added after the document is loaded.

Comment: I think you might be asking how to traverse from X-sibling to Y-sibling?